# Что означает ":" после названия класса?

Tags: c#

Часто натыкаюсь на подобные записи. Что значит ":" после названия класса?

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Comment: inherits and/or implements

Comment: Что наследует? Что это значит и для чего нужно?

Comment: почитайте книжку (или толковый словарь)

Comment: @raspberry367 может стоит про синтаксис языка вначале почитать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В случае если после двоеточия идёт интерфейс, как в данном случае, означает что класс реализует данный интерфейс.

В случае если после двоеточия идёт класс, то `:` означает наследование `class A : B` - `A` наследуется от `B`.

Почитать про наследование - https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.7.php

Интерфейсы - https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.9.php

Comment: а если идет и класс и интерфейс? :)

Comment: @Grundy и какой ответ?)